# Is it possible to return "weird" characters in a char?

Tags: c++, char

I would like to know is it possbile to return "weird" characters, or rather ones that are important to the language
For example: \ ; '
I would like to know that because I need to return them by one function that's checking the unicode value of the text key, and is returning the character by it's number, I need these too.
I get a 356|error: missing terminating ' character
Line 356 looks as following

```
return '\';
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem here is that a backslash is used to escape characters in a literal. For example `\n` is a new line, `\t` is a horizontal tab. In your case, the compiler is seeing `\'` and thinking you mean a `'` character (this is so you could have the `'` character like so: `'\''`). You just need to escape your backslash:

```
return '\\';
```

Despite this looking like a character literal with two characters in it, it's not. `\\` is an escape sequence which represents a single backslash.

Similarly, to return a `'`, you would do:

```
return '\'';
```

The list of available escape sequences are given by Table 7:

[image]

You can have a character literal containing any character from the execution character set and the resulting `char` will have the value of that character. However, if the value does not fit in a `char`, it will have implementation-defined value.

Comment: What about returning ' then?

Answer (score 5):

The backslash is an escape for special characters. If you want a literal backslash you have to escape it with another backslash. Try:

```
return '\\';
```

Answer (score 1):

Any character can be returned.

Yet for some of them, you have to escape it using `backslash`: `\`.

So for returning backslash, you have to return:

```
return '\\';
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a plain backslash use `'\\'`.

In C the following characters are represented using a backslash:

- \a or \A : A bell
- \b or \B : A backspace
- \f or \F : A formfeed
- \n or \N : A new line
- \r or \R : A carriage return
- \t or \T : A horizontal tab
- \v or \V : A vertical tab
- \xhh or \Xhh : A hexadecimal bit pattern
- \ooo : An octal bit pattern
- \0 : A null character
- \" : The " character
- \' : The ' character
- \\ : A backslash (\)

A plain backslash confuses the system because it expects a character to follow it. Thus, you need to "escape" it. The octal/hexadecimal bit patterns may not seem too useful at first, but they let you use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

If the character following the backslash does not specify a legal escape sequence, as shown above, the result is implementation defined, but often the character following the backslash is taken literally, as though the escape were not present.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to return such characters(",',\,{,]...etc) more then once, you should write a function that escapes that characters. I wrote that function once and it is:

```
function  EscapeSpecialChars (_data) {
            try {
                if (!GUI_HELPER.NOU(_data)) {
                    return _data;
                }
                if (typeof (_data) != typeof (Array)) {
                    return _data;
                }
                while (_data.indexOf("&#x0D;") > 0) {
                    _data = _data.replace("&#x0D;", "");
                }
                while (_data.indexOf("\n") > 0) {
                    _data = _data.replace("\n", "\\n");
                }
                while (_data.indexOf("\r") > 0) {
                    _data = _data.replace("\r", "\\r");
                }
                while (_data.indexOf("\t") > 0) {
                    _data = _data.replace("\t", "\\t");
                }
                while (_data.indexOf("\b") > 0) {
                    _data = _data.replace("\b", "\\b");
                }
                while (_data.indexOf("\f") > 0) {
                    _data = _data.replace("\f", "\\f");
                }
                return _data;
            } catch (err) {
               alert(err);
            }

        },
```

then use it like this:

```
return EscapeSpecialChars("\'"{[}]");
```

You should improve the function. It was working for me, but it is not escaping all special characters.